# Angular data from JSON directly in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If have a straight ahead controller:

```
controller: function($scope, $http){
$http.get(templateSource+'/object.customer')
   .then(function(result){
      $scope = result.data;            
    });
}
```

My object.customer file looks like:

```
[{"customer":{"name":"Bert","email":"bert@gmail.com"}}]
```

Now I wanted to access the email, so I did (in HTML)

```
{{customer.email}}
```

But this is incorrect, so my question is, how to access email?

**UPDATE**
Setting:

```
controller: function($scope, $http){
          $http.get(templateSource+'/object.customer')
           .then(function(result){
              $scope.customer = {};
              angular.extend($scope.customer,result.data[0]);
              console.log($scope.customer.email);
            });
        }
```

Gives me in the console.log `unidentified`. However, if I set it to `console.log($scope.customer);` I get:

```
Object 0: 
  Object customer: 
   Object email: "bert@gmail.com"
          name: "Bert"
```

The `console.log(result.data)` is

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    customer: Object
        email: "bert@gmail.com"
        name: "Bert"
```

Comment: You just overwrote your $scope.  You need to do something like `$scope.customers = result.data;`  Also, you are bringing back an array.  If you intend to use the first item (after checking th elength), do `$scope.customer = result.data[0];`

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work, I did an update though.

Comment: Can you post `console.log(result.data)` output?

Comment: Yes, please see the update in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.extend`

```
controller: function($scope, $http){
$http.get(templateSource+'/object.customer')
   .then(function(result){

         angular.extend($scope,result.data[0])            
    });
}
```

Then you can use `$scope.customer.email.` in you controller or `{{customer.email}}` in your html.

Comment: hmm, the output of  `console.log($scope.customer.email);` = `undefined`

Comment: Maybe the update in my post gives a better understanding

Comment: @bvl oh you need an extra`[0]`, check my answer. Can you post `console.log(result.data)` output?

Comment: That makes the array empty (console.log =  Object {}).

Comment: @bvl oh, I got it, you need to apply extend to `$scope` not to `$scope.customer`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks mate! However, for me it seems more logical that it should be $scope.customer do you also know why that is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70439/discussion-between-levi-and-bvl).